# What is the meaning of the following operation?

Tags: c, embedded

What is the meaning of the following operation in C

```
USIC2_CH0->PSR &= ~((uint32_t)USIC_CH_PSR_ASCMode_TFF_Msk);
```

I know that if `A|=B` meant `A=A|B` then what is meant by

`A&=~B;`? Does that meant `A=~(A&B)??`

Comment: It means `A = A & ~B`. Please get a basic C book before getting back to that original source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A &= ~B`  means `A = A & (~B)`, not `A=~(A&B)`.

You can see those two are different if you take A=b010 and B=b110, for example.

In context it's disabling the bits in that PSR bitfield that are set in the constant whose name ends in "TFF_Msk" above.